# Using a Common Lisp user-defined type in defmethod

Tags: methods, common-lisp, dispatch, clos, deftype

I'd like to be able to use a defined type as a parameter specializer to a `defmethod`. The motivation is readability and flexibility to change at a later stage. Somehting like this:

```
(deftype foo () 'fixnum)

(defmethod bar ((x foo)) ...)

(defmethod baz ((x foo)) ...)
```

However this doesn't work. CLtL2 says *"The form deftype does not create any classes."*

So I have to write:

```
(defmethod bar ((x fixnum)) ...)

(defmethod baz ((x fixnum)) ...)
```

An alternative would be to define a class called `foo` which is nothing more than a wrapper around `fixnum` but wouldn't that be an unacceptable overhead for something so simple as a `fixnum`?

Is there a better way?

Comment: CLtL2 is outdated. Please use the Common Lisp HyperSpec [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm), which is based on the ANSI Common Lisp standard.

Comment: CLHS says of `paramet-specializer-names` of `defmethod`: _If parameter-specializer-name is a symbol it names a class_

Comment: In fact CLHS also says _The operator deftype does not create any classes._

Answer (score 12):

Methods don't specialize on types, they specialize on classes, or EQL. This is partly the case because an object may be of many types (e.g. the integer 1 is a FIXNUM, a BIT, an UNSIGNED-BYTE, etc.) and it's not obvious how to decide precedence.

If you want less overhead and user-defined abstractions for types, TYPECASE or ETYPECASE may work better than generic functions and methods.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I have been able to find is using [filtered dispatch](https://common-lisp.net/project/closer/filtered.html).

Something like this:

```
(define-filtered-function bar (x)
  (:filters (:foo (typep x 'foo))))

(defmethod bar :filter :foo (x) ...)
```

However I may resort to Xach's suggestion if the overhead for using this turns out to be too high.